# How can I make a fontawesome icon take me to a webpage (for example my GitHub profile)?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a footer at the bottom of my website which contains some fontawesome icons:
[image]

I have made the icons hoverable, **but how can I make them take me to a website (such as GitHub for the GitHub icon)?**

Demo of what I have so far:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

i:hover {
  color: #AEC6CF;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class='footer'>
  <i class="fab fa-github" style='font-size:30px'></i>
  <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow" style='font-size:30px'></i>
  <i class="fab fa-github" style='font-size:30px'></i>
  <br></br>
  <p>Copyright © 2021 lunAr-creator - Website Design by me (who else? :D)</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

If i use `<a href="github.com"><i class="fab fa-github" style='font-size:30px'></i></a>` as suggested, while it works, I now have a icon in a permanent state of active: How can i stop this from happening?

[image]

**Edit 2:**
The solution was to just specify the color for a link. Thanks for the suggestion CBroe.

```
a:link, i {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: The “permanent state of active” is probably just the text color for links, inherited down to the `i` element. So _specify_ the default color you want for that explicitly then.

Comment: Thankyou :D    All i had to do was ```a:link, i {color: black;}```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the HTML anchor tag to link to either a URL. Change your HTML to this, it should solve your problem.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class='footer'>
  <a href="https://github.com/"><i class="fab fa-github" style='font-size:30px'></i></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow" style='font-size:30px'></i></a>
  <br></br>
  <p>Copyright © 2021 lunAr-creator - Website Design by me (who else? :D)</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put font awesome icons in an anchor tag with a href.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="github.com"><i class="fab fa-github" style='font-size:30px'></i></a>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer :D Whilst this does work, my icon is now in a permanent state of being active? How can I stop this from happening? (see my edited question for an image of this)